# Where are Diaspar and Lys?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, the-city-and-the-stars

In Arthur C. Clarke's *Against the Fall of Night* (and its rewrite *The City and the Stars*), we find a far-future Earth that is a desert wasteland punctuated by two surviving cities, Diaspar and Lys. Is there any indication of where these cities are on the globe and/or which current cities (if any) they developed from?

My recollection of reading *Against the Fall of Night* is that the story takes place so far in the future that nearly everything about the 20th century has been buried for countless eons (and that 20th century cities, or maybe even continents, no longer have any meaning), but I will admit that I might have missed something - maybe a landmark somewhere that indicates that, oh, Diaspar is actually built on top of old Detroit or something. Alternately, did the author ever state where on the globe the cities were?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no hint whatsoever. The story is set so far in the future that there had been ample time for continents to have drifted and old mountains to have been worn down and new ones to rise. Diaspar existed for at least a billion years.

> LIKE A GLOWING JEWEL, the city lay upon the breast of the desert. Once it had known change and alteration, but now Time passed it by. Night and day fled across the desert's face, but in the streets of Diaspar it was always afternoon, and darkness never came. The long winter nights might dust the desert with frost, as the last moisture left in the thin air of Earth congealed-but the city knew neither heat nor cold. It had no contact with the outer world; it was a universe itself.

...

> Since the city was built, the oceans of Earth had passed away and the desert had encompassed all the globe. The last mountains had been ground to dust by the winds and the rain, and the world was too weary to bring forth more. The city did not care; Earth itself could crumble and Diaspar would still protect the children of its makers, bearing them and their treasures safely down the stream of time.

...

> They had lived in the same city, had walked the same miraculously unchanging streets, while more than a billion years had worn away.

Long ago Mankind had faced either invasion or the Fall and destruction of the Moon:

> That great ordeal exhausted mankind; one by one the cities died and the desert rolled over them. As the population fell, humanity began the migration that was to make Diaspar the last and greatest of all cities.

Lys was the one place that survived in an otherwise desert world, nestled in the last remaining mountains of Earth:

> Then Alvin lifted his eyes to the horizon, and there above the trees, sweeping fiom right to left in a great arc that encircled the world, was a line of stone which would have dwarfed the mightiest giants of Diaspar. It was so far away that its details were blurred by sheer distance, but there was something about its outlines that Alvin found puzzling. Then his eyes became at last accustomed to the scale of that colossal landscape, and he knew that those far-off walls had not been built by man.
>
> Time had not conquered everything Earth still possessed mountains of which she could be proud.
>
> For a long time Alvin stood at the mouth of the tunnel, slowly growing accustomed to the strange world in which he had found himself. He was half stunned by the impact of sheer size and space; that ring of misty mountains could have enclosed a dozen cities as large as Diaspar. Search as he might, however, Alvin could see no trace of human life. Yet the road that led down the hillside seemed well-kept; he could do no better than accept its guidance.

Lys had survived much:

> Most of these changes did not affect Lys, but it had its own battle to fight-the battle against the desert. The natural barrier of the mountains was not enough, and many ages passed before the great oasis was made secure.

Finally, Alvin finds a working spaceship and sees both Lys and Diaspar separated by perhaps a third of the circumference of the Earth:

> Alvin did nothing to check the machine; still they rose until the whole of Lys lay spread beneath them, a green island in an ocher sea. Never before had Alvin been so high; when finally they came to rest the whole crescent of the Earth was visible below. Lys was very small now, only an emerald stain against the rusty desert-but far around the curve of the globe something was glittering like a man-coloured jewel. And so for the first time, Hilvar saw the city of Diaspar.